# How to scroll up and down and swipe using real android devices? Appium version 1.7.1

Tags: javascript, android, automation, appium, device

I'm a newbie in automation and I dont know scripting either, but I'm trying to learn automation and we are using java script. I'm trying to scroll the page up and down for the EULA terms, could someone help me? I'm using appium version 1.7.1.
Could also someone recommend a tutorial using android studio and not eclipse.

Thanks,
me.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform scroll / swipe up action with below code:

```
Dimension size = this.driver.manage ()
    .window ()
    .getSize ();
int startX = size.getWidth () / 2;
int startY = size.getHeight () / 2;
int endX = 0;
int endY = (int) (startY * -1 * 0.5);
TouchAction action = new TouchAction (this.driver);
action.press (startX, startY)
    .moveTo (endX, endY)
    .release ()
    .perform ();
```

You can tweak the code to perform left, down and right swipe.

As for the tutorial you are looking for, it's not easy to find a good resource. But to help you with Mobile Automation, I've created an open source framework, [coteafs-appium](https://github.com/WasiqB/coteafs-appium) which you can easily use to Automate the tests. It uses Appium internally. To understand how to use it, see it's wiki on it's GitHub page.

Comment: Thank you, let me try this out. A question for the () do I need to enter anything side? or just the ones for the size? And what do I put on the startX and Y and endX and Y?

Comment: Actually this code snippet is for Java. So () are the paranthesis of a method. And startX and Y are not methods, they are local variables. You can modify endX and endY to change the direction of your swipe. As in code sample, I've a -ve endY which means it will move upwards from the center of the screen.